# facebook link preview generation

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I would like to include facebook link preview on my page. I have a website which is registered with facebook app. I have an input and every time the user enters some url there, I would like to show the same preview as in facebook during a wall post.
How can I do this?

Thanks, Alex A.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to make a request to get the html of the page you want to preview.
Web developers put the stuff they want to be in the facebook preview in meta tags in the head.  They look like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://image.png">
```

Then you just have to get that stuff using jquery

```
var imgSrc = $(html).filter('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content');
```

and put it wherever

```
document.getElementById("wherever").innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" />';
```

edit: Sorry I just realized you probably wanted to do that from the Facebook API. They don't have a method for that, you're just going to have to make your own.